# Run a game on two computers?

Tags: java, networking, greenfoot

I am creating a two-sided war game using Greenfoot. I would like to play it with my brother but I would also like my brother to be able to see only one part of the whole map and me too. Hence, I would like my brother to be able to play it on his computer and I to play it on mine.

This is supposed to be a real-time game but I could make it turn-based if it's too hard.
How do I connect my mac and my brother's mac so that the game runs simultaneously on both ( I would like it to receive both keyboards input).

I have no experience in networking so I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: You need a server in the middle that hosts the game and then a client side on both you and your brothers computer -- the server will then control what both players will see

Comment: Note that you or your brothers computer can also act as the server -- you don't necessarily need another computer -- but the game will be played via a client and they will interact with the game server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This communication between your mac and your brother mac could be done using java sockets. You will be the server, and your brother will be the client. You need to open the server with `ServerSocket` on a specific port and your brother will connect with the help of `Socket`. You can find more details about implementing a java socket [here](https://www.baeldung.com/a-guide-to-java-sockets) ( and look at the 3rd chapter named "Simple Example")